# Convert wave height co-ordinates value in grid format to contour/ vector layer

Tags: mapbox, cluster-analysis, geojson, turfjs, marching-cubes

I have the wave height data in grid format that I would like to convert to vector layer or contour with similar wave height.
The current data looks like this,
[image]

And I would like to create a layer similar to how bathymetry layer (Sea depth layer) looks here from above data format, [image]

I tried using various turfjs methods for isolines and clustering but they didn't seem to give desired output. I'm considering algorithms like marching band, convex hull etc. but not sure what will be the right approach here.
Trying convex hull gave output like this,
[image]

Clustering based on custom logic grouping similar values with step count of 0.5 gave something like this, the clustering look okay but some part of created polygon is going on land,
[image]

Here is the geojson file if anyone would like to give it a try,
[Wave Height Data Gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hearsid/63b0d95031d1073650529be35a9232a4/raw/1fc5d889d09ae9a0f51e563ac0a6ab191541ff75/wave-height.json)

NOTE: These are near real sample values.